# How to redefine a Class Component method in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I want to redefine a function/method inside a Class Component because I want to reuse it.

I tried

```
ClassComponent.prototype.submitForm = async () => {
...
}
```

but no luck.

In Jest, it is possible to do

```
jest.spyOn(class.prototype, 'method').mockImplementation
```

to change the implementation of the method. But I want to do it in React. Is there a way to do this? I need to change that method so I can fully reuse my Component. Thanks

Comment: This may be a silly question on my part, but why? This seems to break the React component abstraction. If you need to make the component more reusable then just update the component to be more general purpose. If you need the function elsewhere then pull it out for other components to import.

Comment: Why don't you simply move the method you want to reuse out of the component and make it a "utility" function that can be imported wherever you need it?

Comment: I think you actually want to use props here. e.g. ``<ClassComponent submitForm={myFunction}/>``

Comment: Hi, I can't move the method outside the Class Component because it is also responsible on states. I just thought of doing this because I have done it with Jest, so maybe its possible with React itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "*because I want to reuse it.*"? And yes, (re)defining a method like that should work. Please post a complete [mcve] with the code that doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: @Bergi oh yeah it works, I forgot that I defined submitForm with arrow function so it is not shown on the Class' prototype. Thanks and sorry for incomplete question

Comment: Also, have you heard of subclasses?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your code to have a better context, but from what I see - you're going in a wrong direction. If you wish to overwrite the behavior of an inner-function inside the component, just overwrite it when a certain condition applies. You can check this condition in an event/hook or on init.